# AndroidRuntimeException:requestFeature() must be called before adding content in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, modal-dialog

I understand this question have been asking many times here but after spending the last 1,5 hour reading and trying to sort out my issue, I can't.

**Problem statement:**

When calling `setStyle` method in `DialogFragment` i get the RuntimeException error stated in the title.

This is my original code, which does not throws this exception:

```
public class MapDialogFragment extends DialogFragment

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Now, I have just added ImmersiveMode throughout my application. As some of you may know, the immersive mode is lost when showing Dialogs, so one must override these fragments and set appropriate flags so that the mode is kept. I have successfully accomplished this - it works. But, I have to comment out line: `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);`, so I am losing my dialog's style and this is the problem.

Having a closer look at the `setStyle` method in the DialogFragment, I can't really see how `requestFeature()` is being invoked:

```
public void setStyle(int style, int theme) {
        mStyle = style;
        if (mStyle == STYLE_NO_FRAME || mStyle == STYLE_NO_INPUT) {
            mTheme = com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_NoFrame;
        }
        if (theme != 0) {
            mTheme = theme;
        }
    }
```

Finally, this is my DialogFragment class where the exception is happening. Note the `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);` and also the clearFlag, which were necessary to have the ImmersiveMode working (hopefully this will be useful for someone):

```
public class MapDialogFragmentv2 extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //I have also tried the code here, before the super.OnCreate but to no avail
        //setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyDialog mDialog = new MyDialog(getActivity());

        mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_dialog, null);

        //Line below throws exception. Needs to be commented out
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
        mDialog.setContentView(view);

        return mDialog;
    }

    public class MyDialog extends Dialog {
        public MyDialog(Context context) {
            super(context);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(MainActivity.getImmersiveModeFlags());
        }

        @Override
        public void show() {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
            super.show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried using a mix of `onCreate`, `onCreateView` and `onCreateDialog` but it didn't work. I also read here at Stackoverflow someone commenting that it was not a good idea to have onCreateView and onCreateDialog at the same time.

And also tried adding the style to my xml layout itself, but also didn't work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to call setStyle() inside onCreate() but rather after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ?

Comment: @dev.bmax yes, I did. In fact, that was the very original code.

Comment: Is your `MapDialogFragmentv2` a nested class inside an `Activity`?

Comment: I'm just commenting (because @dev.bmax did you mean:) This link says to return super() in onCreateView() and not onCreate(), explaining that it's because AlertDialog.Builder hasn't been used: http://www.solardriftsolutions.co.uk/android-fragment-and-dialogfragment/

Comment: The question code (and this solution) both cause the `AndroidRuntimeException` because they call `Window#getDecorView` before `DialogFragment#onCreateView`. I outlined a proper fix in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57813598/9636

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you mash together too many different things and that you don't respect the lifecycle of each class.

Firstly you need to stop nesting classes like you do. This is partly the source of the error. If you really want/have to nest a `Fragment` or `Dialog` then it is important that you declare the nested `Fragments`, `Dialogs` as static. If you don't declare them as static you can cause memory leaks and problems like yours. But the best thing you can do is to only limit yourself to one class per file unless you have an actual reason to nest it. This also has the added benefit of improving readability and maintainability of your code.

But the main cause of your error is that you completely ignore the lifecycle of the `Dialog`. Pretty much all of the following code should be in the proper lifecycle methods of the `Dialog`:

```
mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_dialog, null);

//Line below throws exception. Needs to be commented out
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
mDialog.setContentView(view);
```

---

So to fix your error you need to do 3 things:

1. Either declare `MapDialogFragmentv2` and `MyDialog` static like this:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       ...

       public static class MapDialogFragmentv2 extends Fragment {

           ...

           public static class MyDialog extends Dialog {
               ...
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Or even better move them to their own files all together.

2. Move the code from `onCreateDialog()` in `MapDialogFragmentv2` in the correct lifecycle methods in `MyDialog`. It should then look something like this:

   ```
   public static class MyDialog extends Dialog {

       private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

       public MyDialog(Context context) {
           super(context);

           mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
           getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(MainActivity.getImmersiveModeFlags());

           View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_dialog, null);
           setContentView(view);
       }

       @Override
       public void show() {
           getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
           super.show();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);` to the `onCreate()` method of your `MapDialogFragmentv2` after the `super.onCreate()` call.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
   }
   ```

---

Your `MapDialogFragmentv2` should then just look like this:

```
public static class MapDialogFragmentv2 extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new MyDialog(getActivity());
    }
}
```

---

I tested everything on my Nexus 5 running Android 5.0.1 (Lollipop) and it works.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. I am trying to get this working, but still no luck.
I am ending up with a dialog that is not fullscreen and does not have the style applied to it. I believe I followed everything what you told me, but my implementation is much more complex that what I've showed here - so I will keep trying. In case it works following your suggestion, I will set it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this exception on API 21 and API 23.

```
Fatal Exception: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature + 301(PhoneWindow.java:301)
       at android.app.Dialog.requestWindowFeature + 1060(Dialog.java:1060)
       at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.setupDialog + 403(DialogFragment.java:403)
       at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater + 383(DialogFragment.java:383)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater + 1403(Fragment.java:1403)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 880(FragmentManagerImpl.java:880)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState + 1237(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1237)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1302(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1302)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps + 439(BackStackRecord.java:439)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps + 2075(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2075)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether + 1865(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1865)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute + 1820(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1820)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions + 1726(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1726)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run + 150(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 739(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 95(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 135(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 5221(ActivityThread.java:5221)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke + 372(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 899(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 694(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

This was the offending code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
  View decorView = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
  // do some stuff to decorView
  return dialog;
}
```

**TLDR**

I had to change it to:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  View decorView = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
  // do some stuff to decorView
}
```

**Slightly Deeper Analysis without References**

Technically, it's possible to perform my `Window#getDecorView` call (which triggers `PhoneWindow#installDecor`) any time after `DialogFragment#setupDialog`, and the earliest place to do that seems to be within `onCreateView` (before or after `super.onCreateView` doesn't matter). However, I prefer to let `DialogFragment` cause `PhoneWindow#installDecor` with `DialogFragment#onActivityCreated`, which seems like the normal path. I can then call `Window#getDecorView` within my own `onActivityCreated` AFTER calling `super.onActivityCreated`.

**Super Deep Analysis with Android Source References**

The problem was that `Window#getDecorView` creates window decorations which makes requesting window features throw the `AndroidRuntimeException`. [See the `com.android.impl.policy.PhoneWindow#getDecorView` source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/696cba573e651b0e4f18a4718627c8ccecb3bda0/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#1401):

```
    public final View getDecorView() {
        if (mDecor == null) {
            installDecor();
        }
        return mDecor;
    }
```

[Notice that `com.android.impl.policy.PhoneWindow#installDecor` sets `mContentParent`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/696cba573e651b0e4f18a4718627c8ccecb3bda0/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#2553):

```
    private void installDecor() {
        if (mDecor == null) {
            mDecor = generateDecor();
            mDecor.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
            mDecor.setIsRootNamespace(true);
        }
        if (mContentParent == null) {
            mContentParent = generateLayout(mDecor);
        //  ^ this is our culprit
        //  more window stuff that isn't relevant
    }
```

[And that `requestFeature` throws an `AndroidRuntimeException` if `mContentParent` is set](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/696cba573e651b0e4f18a4718627c8ccecb3bda0/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#191):

```
    public boolean requestFeature(int featureId) {
        if (mContentParent != null) {
            throw new AndroidRuntimeException("requestFeature() must be called before adding content");
        }
        // more requestFeature stuff that isn't relevant
    }
```

And of course [`DialogFragment#setupDialog` calls `Window#requestFeature`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.java#398), which is the where our stack trace comes from:

```
    public void setupDialog(@NonNull Dialog dialog, int style) {
        switch (style) {
            case STYLE_NO_INPUT:
                dialog.getWindow().addFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                // fall through...
            case STYLE_NO_FRAME:
            case STYLE_NO_TITLE:
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        }
    }
```

And one level up in the stack trace, we see that [`DialogFragment#onGetLayoutInflator` calls `setupDialog`, but it calls `onCreateDialog` before that](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.java#379):

```
    public LayoutInflater onGetLayoutInflater(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (!mShowsDialog) {
            return super.onGetLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
        }

        mDialog = onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        if (mDialog != null) {
            setupDialog(mDialog, mStyle);

            return (LayoutInflater) mDialog.getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        return (LayoutInflater) mHost.getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

And [`FragmentManagerImpl` calls `Fragment#performGetLayoutInflater` (which calls `Fragment#onGetLayoutInflator`) right before it calls `Fragment#performCreateView` (which calls `Fragment#onCreateView`), then `Fragment#onViewCreated`, then `Fragment#performActivityCreated` (which calls `Fragment#onActivityCreated`)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.java#1351):

```
Fragment f; // fragment 
if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: " + f);
if (!f.mFromLayout) {
    ViewGroup container = null;
    if (f.mContainerId != 0) {
        if (f.mContainerId == View.NO_ID) {
            throwException(new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Cannot create fragment "
                            + f
                            + " for a container view with no id"));
        }
        container = (ViewGroup) mContainer.onFindViewById(f.mContainerId);
        if (container == null && !f.mRestored) {
            String resName;
            try {
                resName = f.getResources().getResourceName(f.mContainerId);
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                resName = "unknown";
            }
            throwException(new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "No view found for id 0x"
                            + Integer.toHexString(f.mContainerId) + " ("
                            + resName
                            + ") for fragment " + f));
        }
    }
    f.mContainer = container;
    f.performCreateView(f.performGetLayoutInflater(
            f.mSavedFragmentState), container, f.mSavedFragmentState);
    if (f.mView != null) {
        f.mView.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
        setViewTag(f);
        if (container != null) {
            container.addView(f.mView);
        }
        if (f.mHidden) {
            f.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(f.mView);
        f.onViewCreated(f.mView, f.mSavedFragmentState);
        mLifecycleCallbacksDispatcher.dispatchOnFragmentViewCreated(
                f, f.mView, f.mSavedFragmentState, false);
        // Only animate the view if it is visible. This is done after
        // dispatchOnFragmentViewCreated in case visibility is changed
        f.mIsNewlyAdded = (f.mView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                && f.mContainer != null;
    }
}
f.performActivityCreated(f.mSavedFragmentState);
```

[And `DialogFragment` calls `Dialog#setContentView` in `onActivityCreated`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.java#456):

```
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (!mShowsDialog) {
            return;
        }
        View view = getView();
        if (view != null) {
            if (view.getParent() != null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view");
            }
            mDialog.setContentView(view);
        }
        // more irrelevant onActivityCreated stuff
    }
```

Thus, we shouldn't do anything to trigger `PhoneWindow#installDecor` before `DialogFragment#onActivityCreated` so that `DialogFragment` and `PhoneWindow` can play together as they expect.

Then, according to [`onCreateDialog`'s JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)):

> This method will be called after `onCreate(android.os.Bundle)` and before `Fragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)`

And [`Window#requestFeature`'s JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature(int)) confirms what our exception said

> This must be called before setContentView()

Thus, my `Window#getDecorView` caused the crash when I called it any time within `onCreateDialog` because `Window#getDecorView` triggers `PhoneWindow#installDecor`, which sets `PhoneWindow#mContentParent`, which triggers the `AndroidRuntimeException` when `DialogFragment#onGetLayoutInflator` calls `setupDialog` right after `onCreateDialog` and `setupDialog` calls `Window#requestFeature`.

Technically, it's possible to perform my `Window#getDecorView` call (which triggers `PhoneWindow#installDecor`) any time after `DialogFragment#setupDialog`, and the earliest place to do that seems to be within `onCreateView` (before or after `super.onCreateView` doesn't matter). However, I prefer to let `DialogFragment` cause `PhoneWindow#installDecor` with `DialogFragment#onActivityCreated`, which seems like the normal path. I can then call `Window#getDecorView` within my own `onActivityCreated` AFTER calling `super.onActivityCreated`.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  View decorView = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
  // do some stuff to decorView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on some android6.0 phones, I found that I had to request feature before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

Comment: Hello...
Inspect // Watch ...
Your answer is poorly elaborated.
It is useful to insert an effective response, with codes and references. Concluding a practical and efficient solution.
This platform is not just any forum. We are the largest help and support center for other programmers and developers in the world. Review the terms of the community and learn how to post;

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue of not having a Fullscreen Dialog in the MapDialogFragmentv2:

```
@Override 
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        }
    }
```

Now the only thing missing is that the `setStyle()` method is not working. The style is not being set. But it does not throw the original exception mentioned in this post.

Comment: You should remove this an edit your existing answer with an update rather than having two separate answers.

Comment: Sure, let me do that just for you

Answer (score -1):

Ok,

it's almost working now, so I will mark Xaver answer's as correct as it lead me to the right way.

I had to change the `MyDialog` class to:

> public MyDialog(Context context, int theme) {
>    super(context,theme);
>      mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
>
> }

That way I manage to keep the Theme. But for some reason my buttons are not following the Theme. They are all back to default. I am trying to programatically set the style, but with no success for now

> buttonGuess.setBackgroundColor(android.R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle);
>   buttonOk.setBackgroundColor(android.R.style.Widget_Holo_Button);

Nonetheless, it now works as I want it.

Thanks everyone

Comment: This worked because you got rid of your `Window#getDecorView` call. I outlined a proper fix in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57813598/9636